# Error occurs when trying to reference value in .append() / a tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reference `data.url` within an `.append()` with an `a` tag and calling a JavaScript method.

Here is my code:

```
  return $("<div />").append(
    `
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction(${data.url}); return false" class="item-content">
     <div class="item-icon" title="${data.type}">
        <i class="fa fa-${icon}"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="item-title" title="${data.name.length > 48 ? data.name : ""}">
        <span>${data.name}</span>

        <div class="item-tags">
          ${splitTags.map(x => "<span>" + x + "</span>").join(" ")}
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="item-actions">
      <a href="${data.url}" target="_blank"><i class="dx-icon-export"></i></a>
    </div>
    `
  )
}

function myFunction(url) {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

When I click the link though I see this error:

```
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

[image]

What am I missing within this line?

```
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction(${data.url}); return false" class="item-content">
```

Comment: Assuming `data.url` is a string, you need quotes around it.

Comment: `myFunction('${data.url}')`

Comment: is data.url really supposed to be a string?

Comment: i don't know why you are using ${} here, that would be to insert something in the string but its redundant because string is already being interpreted as js not string

Comment: try `onclick = "myFunction(data.url);"`

Comment: @Barmar: I updated the `myFunction(url)` ; also I think you are right. I added the ticks and it appears to work. Still testing and I'll update when I'm done.

Comment: doesn't `'${data.url}'` just evaluate to `data.url+''`?

Comment: @OtherMe No, because the quotes are inside a template literal, so they'll be rendered literally in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, the correct version with using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is

```
onclick="myFunction('${data.url}'); return false;"
```

or with old style Javascript

```
onclick="myFunction(data.url); return false;"
```

Comment: isn't ${} an escape notation for string template?

Comment: It's part of a JavaScript [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Barmar: It is the answer I needed though - even though you already mentioned it in the comment? Why isn't it the answer? Or why did you not put it as the answer?

Comment: @ttaylor27272727 My comment was made before he edited. The original answer wasn't an answer, it was a question.

Comment: @ttaylor27272727 I didn't put it as an answer because I voted to close the question as being just due to a minor typo.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I understand, but your answer (in the comments of the main question) was the correct answer and what he added as the answer. So you were correct - in my opinion.

Comment: I know I was correct, I just didn't think it was worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar post it as an answer and I'll check it! Cause YOU were right!